# Data model problem

Tags: c++, data-structures, boost, data-modeling

Say I have string->index pairs of data, e.g.

```
"hello" -> 0
"best" -> 1
"nice" -> 2
"beautiful" -> 3
```

Now for my flow I want to have logarithmic search on strings, so it is obvious to place this data into `std::map`. But, in some point, I want to have back my data ordered by index (as it is written above) but with with no o(N^2) complexity. How I can do that, boost can help? `std::map` is not useful for the second requirement. How to handle this data **without using N - dependent memory**. (N is the number of elements in map.)

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible. If you want access from both sides of the relation, you need two indices, and thus you will require additional memory.

Comment: It depends on how the data structure is initially populated. If you have all data up front, you can use a `vector<pair<string, int>>` and sort it. Then use binary_search to simulate the map. Resort it when you need the other order. Uses even less storage than the map!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `boost::bimap`. Check the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Is bimap wraps two maps in which, for my case, string will be the key, and in second the index will be the key, and just this two maps are synchronized?

Comment: I don't know how it is implemented..you need to check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct, you can use two maps. One `string to index` and other `index to string`.